# How to get a constant value back in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL query that fetches 50million records .
I want to assign a constant value to each row in the results which should be different everytime I run the query.

So I decided to use system date in the query.

My query looks like :

```
SELECT (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY - HH:MM:SS'), column1,column2,column3
FROM my_table
```

But by the time query execution ends I get different values of HH:MM:SS in the sysdate column.

Is there a way I can make this constant?

Currently My Results Look Like:

```
SYSDATE                     
01-03-2019 01:20:55
01-03-2019 01:20:56
01-03-2019 01:20:57
01-03-2019 01:20:58
01-03-2019 01:20:59
```

Comment: What happens if you cross join a single row table returning the SYSDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there are so many records the database takes time to select all of them.
You can create a variable to hold the `sysdate` before you start the query and select it along with your columns:

```
SET @Date = (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY - HH:MM:SS');

SELECT @Date, column1,column2,column3
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: What would be the Oracle equivalent for this ?

Comment: @jaideepsingh I have no idea. I mainly work with SQL Server, it's been forever since I've done anything in Oracle (or MySql, for that matter)